# searching in multiple random named sub keys in json object in postgres

Tags: json, postgresql, postgresql-11

assuming I have json column which look something like:

```
-- first row:
{
        "a": {
            "x": {"name": "ben", "success": true},
            "y": {"name": "sarah", "success": true},
            "z": {"name": "john", "success": false}
        }
    }

-- second row:
{
        "a": {
            "m": {"name": "issac", "success": true},
            "n": {"name": "jack", "success": true},
        }
    }
```

I want to select all rows which any of their `a.<something>.success` is not true.

in my Example - first row will be selected, second row will be filtered.

As you can see all jsons start with common key `a`, but under it there are unknown number of "childs" with unknown names ('x', 'y', 'z', 'm', 'n').
under each child with unknown name - there is a common known key I'd like to filter by: `success`.

Question is how Can filter such rows?

I got to something I could not complete:

```sql
SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE json_col::json -> 'a' -> <don't know what to put here> -> 'success' = true
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can explode the `json` value with [`json_each()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html#id-1.5.8.22.8.13.2.2.4.1.1.1) into key:value pairs and check the values. That will work in an [`exists`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-subquery.html#FUNCTIONS-SUBQUERY-EXISTS) condition: [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/pstmAbje)

```sql
SELECT * 
FROM my_table
WHERE exists (select from json_each(json_col->'a')_(key,value)
              where (value->>'success') <> 'true');
```

| id | json_col |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | { "a": { "x": {"name": "ben", "success": true}, "y": {"name": "sarah", "success": true}, "z": {"name": "john", "success": false} } } |

If you switch from [`json` to `jsonb`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-json.html#DATATYPE-JSON) you'll be able to speed up the search with a GIN index, get rid of insignificant whitespace, deduplicate and order your keys, get more functions and operators to choose from, like [`@@`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html#FUNCTIONS-JSONB-OP-TABLE) (that, and other `jsonpath`-related features are supported from version 12 onwards):

```sql
ALTER TABLE my_table ALTER COLUMN json_col TYPE jsonb;
CREATE INDEX ON my_table USING GIN(json_col jsonb_path_ops);

SELECT * 
FROM my_table
WHERE json_col @@ '$.a.*.success<>true';
```

If you're on version 11, its [support ended on 2023-11-09](https://www.postgresql.org/support/versioning/). Consider upgrading.

---

To get the name(s) that had `.success<>true`, you can use [`jsonb_path_query()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html#id-1.5.8.22.8.13.2.2.19.1.1.1):

```sql
SELECT id,jsonb_path_query(json_col,'$.a.*?(@.success<>true).name')
FROM my_table
WHERE json_col @@ '$.a.*.success<>true';
```

Comment: perfect! Thank you so much! also will take your upgrade suggestion into account

Comment: can help me with getting the value as a select as well please?

Comment: @maxwell_rob33 What do you mean?

Comment: in my example - I'd like to select the names of the people which passed the filter, ie "issac" & "jack"

Comment: @maxwell_rob33 Are you sure about `issac` and `jack`? My understanding was that in your example they are supposed to be filtered *out*, discarded: *"first row will be selected, second row will be filtered"*. Assuming you want to filter out the second row and get the names from the first one (that does match the *"any of their a.<something>.success is not true"* criterion), do you want all of the names present in the json that matched/wasn't filtered out, or only the name that made it match (having `."success"==not true`)? In this case that would be `john`. [Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/pstmAbje)

Comment: my apologies for the confusion! I'd like to select  the "john" record.

Comment: @maxwell_rob33 Then the example I [added to the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/77773961/4) does exactly that, as well as the last two in [the demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/pstmAbje) above.